# CS0120 Error (C#)

Tags: c#

I am only going to share a bit of the code from this as I do not want to leak what I am currently making, if you require more please do tell, but for now I'll just have to put this.

```
private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DiscordClient discord;
        discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
        {
            x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
            x.LogHandler = Log; // Error CS0120
        });
```

I am trying to achieve logging any errors or anything that happens so I can make a discord bot, for the people who asked.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: What is the signature of the LogHandler method?

Answer (score 2):

CS0120 definition tells it all, refer the same here [MSDN CS0120](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx)

Basically you are accessing a variable that is non-static (presumably "Log") in static "main" method.

Comment: I don't understand how you would do what that tutorial says, I am a complete noob when it comes to C# but I am learning fast.

Comment: Convert "Log" method to static and try.